# What is the availability of 'vector long long'?

Tags: 64-bit, simd, intrinsics, powerpc, altivec

I'm testing on an old PowerMac G5, which is a Power4 machine. The build is failing:

```
$ make
...
g++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 -mcpu=power4 -maltivec -c ppc-simd.cpp
ppc-crypto.h:36: error: use of 'long long' in AltiVec types is invalid
make: *** [ppc-simd.o] Error 1
```

The failure is due to:

```
typedef __vector unsigned long long uint64x2_p8;
```

I'm having trouble determining when I should make the typedef available. With `-mcpu=power4 -maltivec` the machine reports 64-bit availability:

```
$ gcc -mcpu=power4 -maltivec -dM -E - </dev/null | sort | egrep -i -E 'power|ARCH'
#define _ARCH_PPC 1
#define _ARCH_PPC64 1
#define __POWERPC__ 1
```

The [OpenPOWER | 6.1. Vector Data Types](http://openpowerfoundation.org/wp-content/uploads/resources/leabi/content/dbdoclet.50655244_39970.html) manual has a good information on vector data types, but it does not discuss when the `vector long long` are available.

What is the availability of `__vector unsigned long long`? When can I use the typedef?

Comment: Although the G5 had 64 bit *architecture*, AltiVec had no support for 64 bit vector elements back in those days, so no 64 bit ints and no double precision floats either.

Comment: Thanks Paul. We partition code around Power4 (Altivec), Power7 (unaligned loads/stores) and Power8 (in-core crypto). I guess my question is, do we need to use Power5 instead of Power4 for the 64-bit type?

Comment: I'm not sure which generation of POWER introduced 64 bit element types for SIMD - you'd need to do some research to find that out. Obviously you won't be able to test your code on a G5 though, if you need to use 64 bit elements.

Comment: Thanks again Paul. The research is not turning up too much. I can find partial patches to GCC but nothing definitive. Related, would you happen to know when `vec_splats` became available? I'm also catching *`error: 'vec_splats' was not declared in this scope`* on Power4.

Comment: I found some slides which referred to 2 x 64 bit SIMD in POWER 7, but I don't know if that is the earliest. As for `vec_splats` - in AltiVec this was qualified by the element size, so `vec_splat_s8`, `vec_splat_s16`, etc. It's possible that there may be a newer C++ interface which just uses an overloaded prototype `vec_splats` for all of these different intrinsics, but I haven't done much with POWER since the days of the G5 and AltiVec, other than a little benchmarking, so that's just a guess.

Comment: @PaulR: `vec_splats` also allows runtime variables, but the `vec_splat_s16` and so on only compile if they can use the splat-immediate single instruction.  But yeah, it appears `vec_splats` is a good way to tell when gcc thinks 64-bit-element vectors are supported, and it's probably right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL:DR: it looks like POWER7 is the minimum requirement for 64-bit element size with AltiVec.  This is part of [VSX (Vector Scalar Extension)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltiVec#VSX_(Vector_Scalar_Extension)), which Wikipedia confirms first appeared in POWER7.

---

It's very likely that gcc knows what it's doing, and enables 64-bit element-size vector intrinsics with the lowest necessary `-mcpu=` requirement.

```
#include <altivec.h>

auto vec32(void) {       // compiles with your options: Power4
    return vec_splats((int) 1);
}

// gcc error: use of 'long long' in AltiVec types is invalid without -mvsx
vector long long vec64(void) {
    return vec_splats((long long) 1);
}
```

(With `auto` instead of `vector long long`, the 2nd function compiles to returning in two 64-bit integer registers.)

Adding `-mvsx` lets the 2nd function compile.  Using `-mcpu=power7` also works, but power6 doesn't.

[source + asm on Godbolt (PowerPC64 gcc6.3)](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAViAIzkDO6ArqatiAOQCkATAGYCAO1QAbVjgDUvQQGEAhuKIEAbtlQA6JHNy8ADAEFDRjahKlpTAsBHZM00UWnmA%2BgAdJTN01TLFKwhzS2tbe0dnaQAPcicRFz8A0gBKU14AdgAhU2k86QB6ApCyMLsHeJcAI38mFzkAEVdNXy9FIl9Bfgh6NMEsvKLpTv5pRRFHFml0EWmRcQBPaQB3MgBrFeIkaQwROvGiJnTjfMKC6Xlmi1KiBY9sMYnpGsU66WxxbABbbASwgC8Hjh7hMmHNpEQkA9bvdpgAzCFQsakYC5fJDDBfDwET5gkhjayWbAFUgfdCKRzjRxqJheIjLOKQ7CksDcMEidBhETAT7xOqkVgWAgzaRwm5IAhHE75EpWGzlSJ/F5vRpXVridpMCBJDWpOQ5YxovLRWSCJruCmOCCxZ61Ih9A1GU6kojsWbRfXpDINY5mTSheURSpqrysHw6wJuXZvYL%2B0qBipRaJpQ3ZI1nWVlINRZX1M1q2kajpMLo9B3pzMJxXVO2m80tQuasv6wbncTEZnKaT0aRIV4Qu4PZzpoaNw7SbX%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%2BC7VYF2MBcXMC4Vl0pCzp3Y%2BQlX8BkrUGGTw8k0TokSQNh31SjZ2jcwGPfd77MQCg/Mbbza8A0LIviWLEtSziRCy9QCuM0rPGkPr6ua5uuuLKb3zjDyDufWb/pp1bn023bR9q4lztDTdh7P%2BB1fb%2BwgIHYOwo9g8HDpHaOzFWL3VIFxKiyhVDmAzuZHiPwmC53ygXIGR16ZDRGuXB6T1q5vQ%2BnXQgoQm5xHkK3Da7d%2BCd0xt3HGYMIZCAMATOK9A%2BEGA6uJGm08S6z3RpNLGRD%2BAkMZmjDhP1yBvg/MlcSQA)

```
# with auto without VSX:
vec64():     # -O3 -mcpu=power4 -maltivec -mregnames
    li %r4,1
    li %r3,1
    blr
```

```
vec64():  # -O3 -mcpu=power7 -maltivec -mregnames
.LCF2:
0:  addis 2,12,.TOC.-.LCF2@ha
    addi 2,2,.TOC.-.LCF2@l
    addis %r9,%r2,.LC0@toc@ha
    addi %r9,%r9,.LC0@toc@l       # PC-relative addressing for static constant, I think.
    lxvd2x %vs34,0,%r9            # vector load?
    xxpermdi %vs34,%vs34,%vs34,2
    blr


 .LC0:    # in .rodata
    .quad   1
    .quad   1
```

---

And BTW, `vec_splats` (splat scalar) with a constant compiles to a single instruction.  But with a runtime variable (e.g. a function arg), it compiles to an integer store / vector load / vector-splat (like the `vec_splat` intrinsic).  Apparently there isn't a single instruction for int->vec.

The `vec_splat_s32` and related intrinsics *only* accept a small (5-bit) constant, so they only compile in cases where the compiler can use the corresponding splat-immediate instruction.

This [Intel SSE to PowerPC AltiVec migration](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/W51a7ffcf4dfd_4b40_9d82_446ebc23c550/page/Intel%20SSE%20to%20PowerPC%20AltiVec%20migration) looks mostly good, but got that wrong (it claims that `vec_splats` splats a signed byte).